# How can I find where a Record Type object's field value Pick-list is getting its values from? - Task & Event objects

Tags: picklist, record-type

So far when I'm asked to add a value to a record-type picklist I can go into the field of the object, add the value, and then go into the record type picklist and add it to available values.

For this current request I'm asked to add a value to a record type picklist. I see the value is not available in the 'available values' but there is also no field in the object that holds the picklist values that are currently available. I checked global picklists, but that hasn't helped.

What am I missing, and how can I reverse engineer to find where these picklist values are coming from?

Comment: You're trying to add a value to the list of available record types?

Comment: Can you clarify which values are you referring to? Picklist values or the values on record types?

Comment: In the Task object I'm trying to add a value to a specific record type picklist

Comment: Could please share a screenshot of the field.I would be more helpful to debug

Comment: RecordType is not a picklist. You can add value in record type by following this in classic. Setup -> Customize -> Activities -> Task Record Types ->New

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I am explaining this correctly. I have a record type that is named 'Investment' and I want to add a new value to the picklist called 'Products', but I am unable to find where the values in Products resides in. Does that make sense? Sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So I think I may have not communicated the question properly, but I have the answer so I'm going to answer it.

My issue is someone wanted to add a new value to a 'Product' picklist for the Task object for a specific record type layout. The record type is 'Investment'.

Usually when I see this I go into the fields of the object in question, find the field - (Products) add the value, and go back to the record type specified and add it to the picklist for the record type.

This time around I was not able to find the Products field in the object (Task).

**ANSWER**: You can create custom fields for task and events however, the process varies in comparison to creating custom fields for other objects. Since events and tasks are both listed as part of the activities object you will need to create your custom fields for task and events by navigating to:

Classic: Setup | Customize | Activities | Activity Custom Fields | New

Lightning:  Gear icon | Setup | Object Manager | Activity | Field & Relationship | New

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205377&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1

My 'Product' field was in the Activity Object not the Task Object